# Log file is not specified Laravel 4 using pitchanon/facebook-connect

Tags: facebook, laravel, authentication

I am using Laravel 4.2.17
with pitchanon/facebook-connect in my composer.json

Everything were working great using this line to login with facebook in my site

```
$hybridauth = new \Hybridauth\Provider\Facebook( ['callback' => 'mysite.com/facebook', 'keys' => ['id' => 'xxxxxxxxxx', "secret" => 'xxxxxxxx'], 'debug_mode' => false]);
```

but later this was causing this error

> [2015-08-11 15:49:24] local.ERROR: exception 'Hybridauth\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Log file is not specified.' in vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/src/Logger/Logger.php:65

**Update**
To solve this, i add 3 new params

```
$hybridauth = new \Hybridauth\Provider\Facebook( ['callback' => 'mysite.com/facebook', 'keys' => ['id' => 'xxxxxxxxxx', "secret" => 'xxxxxxxx'], 'debug_mode' => false], null, null, new \Hybridauth\Logger\Logger(\Hybridauth\Logger\Logger::DEBUG, '/home/fide/app/storage/logs/laravel.log')
```